# What is the origin of the name 'master' as default branch name?

Tags: git, history

I am seeing that the new name for the git default branch will be changed from **master** to **main**
And that made me wonder:

- Where did that *master* name come from?

I did not find anything about it on the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc), and was wondering if somebody had some answers or some archives/anecdotes on this naming decision.

I'd like to trace the origin of the name.

Comment: The name was introduced in the commit https://github.com/git/git/commit/cad88fdf8d1ebafb5d4d1b92eb243ff86bae740b.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the history of computing than a practical question about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2019-May/msg00066.html)

> - The first appearance of "`master`" in Git is in a [CVS helper script](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e91311ae750af9bf2e3517b1e701288ac3066b9) by Linus, May 2005 (actually [commit 3c4347c](https://web.archive.org/web/20200707031046/https://repo.or.cz/cogito.git/commit/3c4347c8b64fb516bc097ab174c3247113b7603d) by [Petr Baudis](https://web.archive.org/web/20220616084301/https://twitter.com/xpasky/status/1272280760280637441), Apr. 2005):
> - Why is that branch called `master`? Probably because [BitKeeper uses "`master`" for its main branch](http://www.bitkeeper.org/tips.html#_how_do_i_rebase_my_work_on_top_of_a_different_changeset) (with a [master-slave terminology](https://github.com/bitkeeper-scm/bitkeeper/blob/master/doc/HOWTO.ask#L223))

And from "[Git Origin Story](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/git-origin-story)", Linus Torwalds used BitKeeper before switching and developing Git.

The result was "[Allow overriding the default name of the default branch](https://public-inbox.org/git/pull.656.git.1591823971.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/#u)".

Comment: Petr Baudis [on Twitter](https://web.archive.org/web/20220616084301/https://twitter.com/xpasky/status/1272280760280637441) stating that it's master as in "master recording", but also responds to that mailing list post above and says he may indeed have been influenced by BitKeeper, and wishes he'd chosen `upstream/main` instead of `origin/master`.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Thank you for the links. I have included them in the answer.